# Replace a value in file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file which has a line containing a string cpu_limit: {max: 1, min: 1}

Max value and min value keeps on changing.

Now i need to change the max and min to value to 100,Is it possible to do via sed.

Answer (score 0):

give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed -r 's/(cpu_limit:\s*\{)[^}]*(.*)/\1max:100, min:100\2/' file
```

use `-i` to do in-place change, so that the change can be written back to the file.